# How to use C# code to generate app bar style buttons?

Tags: windows-store-apps

say I create an app bar button in XAML using the following code

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource PicturesAppBarButtonStyle}"     
        AutomationProperties.Name="{StaticResource localizedPictureText"}/>
```

How can I use C# code to create such a button with the same effect?

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone I found the genius who has answered another question which is similar to mine.
[How To Create A Bottom Or Top AppBar in Windows Store App Using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577768/how-to-create-a-bottom-or-top-appbar-in-windows-store-app-using-c)

However I followed his answer and wrote the code

```
b1.Style =  Application.Current.Resources["EditAppBarButtonStyle"] as Style;
```

I got an error called
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Is this because I am testing the code on my local machine (just a normal desktop)?

Hope someone can confirm it. Thanks.

Comment: Got the answer, it is just because that style is commented in the file Common/StandardStyles.xaml.  Just uncomment all the styles and there is no error